# mismatched input 'GROUP' expecting <EOF> SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a process on Spark which uses SQL for the most part. In one of the workflows I am getting the following error:

> mismatched input 'GROUP' expecting

```py
spark.sql("SELECT state, AVG(gestation_weeks) "
          "FROM natality "
          "WHERE state is not null "
          "HAVING AVG(gestation_weeks) > (SELECT AVG(gestation_weeks) FROM natality) "
          "GROUP BY state").show()
```

I cannot figure out what the error is for the life of me

I've tried checking for comma errors or unexpected brackets but that doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: `Having` should follow `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL constructs should appear in the following order:

```
SELECT
FROM 
WHERE 
GROUP BY **
HAVING   **
ORDER BY
```